# Inserting Lorentz vectors in Lagrangian in FeynRules

Tags: feyncalc

I am writing the model file for an effective theory. The lagrangian of the theory has an external physical lorentz vector (say velocity in Heavy Quark Effective Theory where the Kinetic part is  $\bar\psi \bar v.\bar D \psi$) 
I have written the following .fr file(the mass term is just a simple illustration):

M$ModelName = "HQET1";

M$Information = {
Authors -> {"Abhishek Pal"},
      Date -> "12/06/2009"
         Institutions -> {"Indian Institute of Science"},
       Version -> 1
   };

(***** Parameter list ******)

M$Parameters = {

vel == {ParameterType -> External,
    Indices -> {Index[Lorentz]},
            Description -> "velocity of heavy quark"
    }
    }

(***** Particle classes list ******)

M$ClassesDescription = {
  S[1] == {FeynRules`ClassName -> h,
              SelfConjugate -> False,
          Mass -> mh,
              Width -> 0
    }
  }

L := hbar vel[alpha].del[h,alpha]+1/2 vel[mu].vel[mu] (h*hbar)^2;

However on running the program the output comes as 
 - - - FeynRules interface to FeynArts - - -

```
  C. Degrande C. Duhr, 2013

  Counterterms: B. Fuks, 2012
```

Calculating Feynman rules for L1

Starting Feynman rules calculation for L1.

Expanding the Lagrangian...

Collecting the different structures that enter the vertex.

1 possible non-zero vertices have been found -> starting the computation: 1 / 1.

1 vertex obtained.

Writing FeynArts model file into directory HQET

Writing FeynArts generic file on HQET.gen.

Warning : the following lorentz structure or part of the lorentz structure is not writen in the generic file

Power[vel[Pattern[a,Blank[]]],2]

How do I ensure that the lorentz structure is taken into account in the mod file ?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible out of the box. The problem is that FeynRules cannot even recognize your propagator, since the HQET propagator doesn't match to anything from the list in Sec 3.1 of the FR manual. But even supposed that you manage to generate the diagrams, how are you going to compute that? HQET-type integrals are quite special and are not handled by FormCalc or LoopTools.

Comment: agreed so I was thinking of treating the 4-velocity itself as a massless vector field. That way it calculates the vertices. Next we need to replace the polarization and the internal propagator lines for the velocity field with just the four velocity. I am still trying to implement it. Please let me know if you get something.

Comment: Well, this way you will get a QQ^+ v- vertex, which looks totally different from the HQET propagator with 1/v.q. So it is much more work than just replacing polarization vector by v. AFAIK people who do big HQET calculations use qgraf and FORM, c.f. Sec.3 of  arXiv:1510.07803. But they don't publish their source codes...